# Hadoop startup error on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, logging, hadoop

I am following [Michael](http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-single-node-cluster/)

When I try to start hadoop `**/usr/local/hadoop/bin/start-all.sh**`

I get the following error

```
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../logs’: Permission denied
chown: cannot access ‘/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../logs’: No such file or directory
starting namenode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../logs/hadoop-stratageeksadmin-   namenode-stratageeksadmin-ubuntu.out
/usr/local/hadoop/bin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 136: /usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../logs        /hadoop-stratageeksadmin-namenode-stratageeksadmin-ubuntu.out: No such file or directory
head: cannot open ‘/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../logs/hadoop-stratageeksadmin-namenode-stratageeksadmin-ubuntu.out’ for reading: No such file or directory
localhost: mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../logs’: Permission denied
localhost: chown: cannot access ‘/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../logs’: No such file or directory
localhost: starting datanode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../logs/hadoop-stratageeksadmin-datanode-stratageeksadmin-ubuntu.out
localhost: /usr/local/hadoop/bin/hadoop-daemon.sh: line 136: /usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../logs/hadoop-stratageeksadmin-datanode-stratageeksadmin-ubuntu.out: No such file or directory
localhost: head: cannot open ‘/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../logs/hadoop-stratageeksadmin-datanode-stratageeksadmin-ubuntu.out’ for reading: No such file or directory
localhost: mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../logs’: Permission denied
localhost: chown: cannot access ‘/usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../logs’: No such file or directory
localhost: starting secondarynamenode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../logs/hadoop-stratageeksadmin-secondarynamenode-stratageeksadmin-ubuntu.out
```

Comment: Make sure that the user that runs the `start-all` command has write access to the specified directories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has been mentioned in that tutorial:

> Make sure to change the owner of all the files to the hduser user and hadoop group.

Please, fire the below command in hadoop installation directory.
For example, if installation directory is `/usr/local/hadoop`:

```
sudo chown -R hduser:hadoop hadoop
```